# Wrap Text in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to wrap text in a UITextView so that the textView does not extend beyond the edges of the screen.  I'd like the first line to be indented x characters, then any subsequent lines indented another y characters.  For example, if the string is:

```
aaaaabbbbbcccccdddddeeeeefffffggggghhhhh
```

I might want (for a particularly narrow screen that only displays 14 characters) with both x=4 and y=4:

```
    aaaaabbbbbcccc
        cdddddeeee
        efffffgggg
        ghhhhh
```

What I get now is:

```
    aaaaabbbbbcccc
cdddddeeeeefffffgg
ggghhhhh
```

I could calculate how many characters fit on the screen and manipulate each string accordingly, but is there a simple way to do this using Swift functions?

Comment: Use constraints to keep the textView from expanding outside the view.

Comment: In your example, you want to indent on left or right? I didnt understand that... The first substring takes up the whole line, the second one is indented in relation to the right margin while the third one to the start of the second substring...

Comment: @Asol: they should be indented the same amount of space from the left.  The second and third substrings above are both indented 4 characters from the left.

Comment: @The Swift Coder: how do I do that?  I've tried `sizeToFit` but all text disappears.  Then how would I get the indentation?

Comment: You can use Interface Builder, or add programmatic constraints to pin the view and keep it from expanding to infinity. That seems to be the issue at the moment, since your textView isn't even allowing text to be on multiple lines. I'd begin with a horizontal x and width constraint.

Comment: @The Swift Coder: the text is wrapping now (I had overlooked constraining it to the view width when in landscape where it only occupies half the screen).  And I've modified the original question.